# Incrementing a string by one for each iteration of loop

Tags: java

I have some string and for each string I have to increment value of it's last element by 1.

For Example:

Suppose I have a temp variable which gets a string each time when loop iterates.

Strings are in following forms:

```
String s1=abc,cde=1 //here I want to increment value of cde by 1

String s2=gef,pqwl=let2-1  //here also I want to increase value by 1
```

These type of string can come randomly, so I need to provide such a handling 
whether the string is of type s1 or s2 it should increment its value by 1 every time.

```
Expected output:

abc,cde=2
if same string comes again: abc,cde=3
gef,pqwl=let2-2  
if same string comes again: gef,pqwl=let2-3
and so on
```

Please help

Comment: String's are not numerical values, use ints or Integers instead

Comment: The problem is values are coming in string and in the form as mentioned above and for each iteration of loop I have to write that data in xml by incrementing values

Comment: use a map, with the string as key, and the Integer as value

Comment: I treid with that but it was not working as values against each '=' are in different for .It will be sometimes like normal integer like 1,2 and sometimes like as mentioned in question let2-1

Comment: has it occurred to you that probably your code was wrong?

Comment: So do you want to increment the last digit in that string, otherwise keep the string as is?

Comment: @davida. everytime such type of string will come it will increment it by 1 and will write it to a file

Comment: Could do something like `cde = new BigInteger(cde).add(BigInteger.ONE).toString();` but I think you really ought to take a step back and see the problem from a new angle. It's an odd road you're going down.

Comment: @Henrik I will try with this

Answer (score 0):

While you can use a String to store a number, it is essentially a sequence of characters, and as such cannot be incremented (in fact, the statement "increment a String" makes about as much sense as the statement "increment the smell of roses").

I would suggest you have a look at the tutorial for data types in Java:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

If you're trying to store a number, then you're probably looking for `byte`, `int`, `long` or `short` if you want a whole number, or `float` or `double` for decimal numbers. If you're trying to create an association (that is, an integer value mapped to a String key), then you should use an implementation of `java.util.Map`, such as `HashMap`, or in a few specific use cases `TreeMap`.

Incrementing the value of a number stored as value in a map is simply a matter of replacing the value with the given key:

```
Map<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
// Add value
map.put(key, originalValue);
// Increment value by 1
map.put(key, map.get(key)+1);
```

In addition, if you're using Java 8, you could also use `replaceAll` to increment all values in a Map:

```
map.replaceAll((key,value) -> value+1);
```

Comment: How can I increase it in case if value is let2-1

Comment: Short answer: you can't, because Strings can't be incremented.

Long answer: you need to extract the numerical value from your String and reconstruct it, which is non-trivial but definitely not impossible. You could parse the String using regular expressions, and then use a `java.util.regex.Matcher` to extract both the trailing integer and the preceding text, and then create a new String with the preceding tet and the incremented integer.

Comment: Can't we do it by splitting a string

Comment: Only if the format is predictable (i.e. you know all possible separators). Say you use `String.split("-")` then you'll be able to parse `let2-1` and have `1` as the second element in your array. But that won't help with input `let21`, since it has no separator, or `let2,1`, which has a different separator and will make your implementation more difficult if people start inputting `let2-3-1` since you'll now have 3 elements in your array.